Feature Transformation for Domain Adaptation: Modifying Abnormal Data to Match Normal Feature Distributions
Let $X$ be a dataset consisting of $N$ instances, where each instance is described by a set of features $\text{feat}_0, \ldots, \text{feat}_m$, and let $Y$ denote the corresponding target values. Suppose that $X$ is partitioned into two subsets: $X_0$, representing normal cases, and $X_1$, representing abnormal cases, with their respective target sets $Y_0 = \{0\}$ and $Y_1 = \{1\}$.
The objective is to explore potential modifications to the feature values of instances in $X_1$ such that, after transformation, the target values of the modified instances are mapped to the target set $Y_0 = \{0\}$. In other words, the transformation should adjust the features of $X_1$ while ensuring that the modified instances exhibit the same characteristics as those in the normal subset $X_0$, effectively restoring their normality.
What  algorithms or techniques are available for achieving such a feature transformation, particularly in scenarios where the goal is to align feature distributions or facilitate domain adaptation between the subsets $X_0$ and $X_1$?
